# How i can list Two Table with One-Many Relation on ListViews

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, relational-database

[my DB like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXSZj.jpg)
I've searched many pages, videos but i couldnt find an example for that and i couldnt do this example.
On my project, there is not any add, delete and update button. I have all data in my sqlite DB.

And on this program, my main table will list on first main layout on listview. When i click a row, i have to see other datas on related table on listview. (when i click a customer on listview, i will see its all orders on another listview. All data on my tables.)

I hope i explained my issue. Is there anybody who will offer me an example for this.

Comment: You could use a SELECT query with an appropriate JOIN to extract a cursor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. i also used SELECT and JOIN. But i have some problem on my program about programs logic. I have run time error. I think, maybe i can solve my problem with an example, tutorial etc. but i couldnt find a program like i said. Should i post all my example's codes in here ? Or where, how i can find an example like i said?

Comment: Your schema seems very simple! You should not have any problem if your write your query right! I think the problem is on your query! Can you post that

Answer (score 0):

As you already know the customer you can do a very simple query to get a cursor from which the ListView can be built/re-built.

Then the following would return such a cursor:-

```
public Cursor getCustomerOrders(long customerref) {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query("Orders",null,
                "CustomerID=?",
                new String[]{Long.toString(customerref)},
                null,null,null);
    }
```

Where **customerref** is the the value in the **ID** column of the **Customers** table.

You would invoke it (assuming a `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass named `DBHelper`) using :-

```
Cursor orderlist = getCustomerOrders(clicked_customer);
```

### Working Example

#### Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView customerlist;
    ListView orderlist;
    Cursor customers;
    Cursor orders;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca_customers;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca_orders;
    DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customerlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customerlist);
        orderlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.orderlist);

        //Create some randomish data for 3 Customers
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Cursor chkforempty = dbh.getWritableDatabase().query(DBHelper.CUSTOMERSTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        boolean chk = (chkforempty.getCount() > 0);
        chkforempty.close();
        if (!chk) {
            for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
                String suffix = Integer.toString(i);
                dbh.insertCustomer("Compnay" + suffix,"Name " + suffix, "Last Name " + suffix);
                int randomorders = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;
                for (int i2=0; (i2 < randomorders) || (i2 < 10); i2++ ) {
                    dbh.insertOrder((long) i,"Destination " + Integer.toString(i2));
                }
            }
        }

        //Back to the real code
        customers = dbh.getCustomers();
        orders = dbh.getCustomerOrders(-1); // get none at first
        sca_customers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                customers,
                new String[]{DBHelper.CUSTOMER_COMPANY_COL},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);

        sca_orders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                orders,
                new String[]{DBHelper.ORDER_DESTINATION_COL},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);
        customerlist.setAdapter(sca_customers);
        orderlist.setAdapter(sca_orders);

        customerlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                orders = dbh.getCustomerOrders(l);
                sca_orders.swapCursor(orders);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### DBHelper.java (SQLiteOpenHelper subclass)

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase";
    private static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String CUSTOMERSTABLE = "customers";
    public static final String ORDERSTABLE = "orders";

    public static final String CUSTOMER_ID_COL = "_id";
    public static final String CUSTOMER_COMPANY_COL = "company";
    public static final String CUSTOMER_NAME_COL = "name";
    public static final String CUSTOMER_LASTNAME_COL = "lastname";

    private static final String CUSTOMERSTABLE_CREATESQL =
            "CREATE TABLE " + CUSTOMERSTABLE +
                    "(" +
                    CUSTOMER_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    CUSTOMER_COMPANY_COL + " TEXT, " +
                    CUSTOMER_NAME_COL + " TEXT, " +
                    CUSTOMER_LASTNAME_COL + " TEXT " +
                    ")";
    public static final String ORDER_ID_COL = "_id";
    public static final String ORDER_CUSTOMERREF_COL = "customerid";
    public static final String ORDER_DATE_COL = "date";
    public static final String ORDER_DESTINATION_COL = "destination";

    private static final String ORDERSTABLE_SCREATSQL =
            "CREATE TABLE " + ORDERSTABLE +
                    "(" +
                    ORDER_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    ORDER_CUSTOMERREF_COL + " INTEGER, " +
                    ORDER_DATE_COL + " LONG DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                    ORDER_DESTINATION_COL + " TEXT " +
                    ")";

    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CUSTOMERSTABLE_CREATESQL);
        db.execSQL(ORDERSTABLE_SCREATSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,
                          int oldversion,
                          int newversion) {

    }

    public long insertCustomer(String company, String name, String lastname) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_COMPANY_COL,company);
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_NAME_COL,name);
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_LASTNAME_COL,lastname);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(CUSTOMERSTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertOrder(long customerid, String destination) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ORDER_CUSTOMERREF_COL,customerid);
        cv.put(ORDER_DESTINATION_COL,destination);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(ORDERSTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getCustomers() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(CUSTOMERSTABLE,
                null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Cursor getCustomerOrders(long customerref) {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(ORDERSTABLE,null,
                ORDER_CUSTOMERREF_COL+"=?",
                new String[]{Long.toString(customerref)},
                null,null,null);
    }
}
```

Note, names that suit myself have been used. This has only been tested for very basic functionality.

When run initially it shows:-

[image]

Clicking on Compnay1 results in :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example Mike. But i couldnt make my app. Can you help me how can i link my tables? When i click a row, i only can see customer name. I couldnt list the orders. I upload my example to github. This is the link. https://github.com/ctunc66/customerOrderExample